# How to handle linq statement returning exception when no file found

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code to fetch the recently modified file

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
string partialFileName = "partialFileName";
FileInfo recentlyModFile = (from files in dirInfo.GetFiles(partialFileName + "*") orderby files.LastWriteTime descending select files).First();
```

Concern is that when there is no file that matches the criteria then it returns exception which obviously is bound to happen and I am looking for ways to handle the same.

I tried putting the above piece of code in try catch block but that didn't help. It would be helpful if someone can let me know how to fix this.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-6.0) instead of `First()`

`First()` will throw an exception if there is no result data.

`FirstOrDefault()` returns the default value (null) if there is no result data.

```
FileInfo recentlyModFile = (from files in dirInfo.GetFiles(partialFileName + "*") orderby files.LastWriteTime descending select files).FirstOrDefault();
```